# Can't debug CUDA: CUDA dynamic parallelism debugging is not supported in preemption mode

Tags: cuda

I have CUDA 5.5, latest drivers, Nsight studio 3.1 for VC2010 on Windows7 64bit.
The target machine has a headless Titan card, and another simple NVidia card, to which the monitor is connected.

I'm trying to debug my CUDA code which includes some dynamic parallelism. Whenever I click "Start CUDA Debugging" in VC, I get this error from Nsight Monitor: `CUDA dynamic parallelism debugging is not supported in preemption mode`. [From what little I found regarding this issue](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/536202/debugging-dynamic-parallelism-and-preemption-mode/), this is because I'm trying to debug CUDA on the same device that drives my screen. This however is not true, as I mentioned, I have a separate card to drive the screen.
I went even further with this, disconnected the monitor from the second card as well, rebooted, and set up remote debugging from a different machine. Same result.
Does anyone have an idea how to tackle this?

Comment: In the thread you quoted from the NVIDIA forum there is a suggestion by vacaloca (subsequent to your post here) on how solving the problem. Did you try that?

Comment: @JackOLantern: I've disabled TDR a long time ago (my kernels run for several minutes at a time without returning execution to host).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the monitor's tray icon, check "Options\CUDA\Debugger".  Except TCC GPUs, the others are by default force "Software Preemption".

You can set "Desktop GPUS must use Software Preemption" and "Headless GPUs must use software preemption" to false. And make sure in you VisualStuido, the setting "Nsight\Options\CUDA\Preemption Preference" is "Prefer no Software Preemption".

Comment: I won't be able to test this in the near future (going on vacation). Could you direct me to where I can read about **SW preemption**? I can't find anything coherent in the documentation, only fragmented bits and pieces. I don't understand what this option does.

Comment: When no SW preemption, during debugging, the GPU will be freezed when breakpoint breaks (that freeze your display if you are using only 1 GPU), that requires you to use a non-display GPU as debugging target, and highly suggest to use remote configuration.